# How to print PythonTransformedDStream

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to run word count example integrating AWS Kinesis stream and Apache Spark. Random lines are put in Kinesis at regular intervals.

```
lines = KinesisUtils.createStream(...)
```

When I submit my application, `lines.pprint()` I don't see any values printed.

Tried to print the `lines` object and I see `<pyspark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream object at 0x7fa235724950>`

How to print the `PythonTransformedDStream` object? and check if the data is received.

I'm sure there is no credentials issue, if I use false credentials I get access exception.

Added the code for reference

```
import sys

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kinesis import KinesisUtils, InitialPositionInStream

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="SparkKinesisApp")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

    lines = KinesisUtils.createStream(ssc, "SparkKinesisApp", "myStream", "https://kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com","us-east-1", InitialPositionInStream.LATEST, 2)

    # lines.saveAsTextFiles('/home/ubuntu/logs/out.txt')
    lines.pprint()

    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
                           .map(lambda word: (word, 1))
                           .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)

    counts.pprint()

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got it working.

The example code which I referred on https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kinesis-asl/src/main/python/examples/streaming/kinesis_wordcount_asl.py has a wrong command to submit application.

The correct command with which I got it working is

```
$ bin/spark-submit --jars external/spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11-2.1.0.jar --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11:2.1.0 /home/ubuntu/my_pyspark/spark_kinesis.py
```

Comment: not sure why are you submitting jars as well as packages?

Answer (score 2):

Since `lines.pprint()` doesn't print anything, can you please confirm that you execute:

```
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

as mentioned in the example here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0/examples/src/main/python/streaming/network_wordcount.py

> `pprint()` should work when the environment is configured correctly:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations-on-dstreams

> **Output Operations on DStreams**
>
> `print()` -   Prints the first ten elements of every batch of data in a DStream on the driver node running the streaming application. This
>   is useful for development and debugging. Python API This is called
>   `pprint()` in the Python API.

Comment: I've already tried the network word count program and `pprint` is working for that, so I guess, environment is configured appropriately. Also, the mentioned two lines are available at the end of my code. The program runs until I press ctrl+c.

Comment: @ArunDhaJ - did you install netcat server (http://landoflinux.com/linux_netcat_command.html) and execute it using `$ nc -lk 9999` ? Did you enter words in the netcat console which will be input to your spark streaming program?

Comment: I did tried network word count program with `nc` and successfully executed it. I'm only facing issues with Amazon Kinesis integration. I'm publishing random sentences to kinesis stream, however my spark client doesn't pick it and process.